# how to copy directory of specific files in batch file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

```
c:/--> folder1-->
      folder2->
           img001.png
           img002.jpg
           img003.png
```

I having kind of folder structure.

I need to copy a single file from this folder to Destination folder.

```
source : "c:\folder1\folder2\imgoo1.png"
Destination:"D:\folder1\folder2\imgoo1.png"
```

need output:

```
D:/--> folder1-->
      folder2->
           img001.png
```

Note:I need batch file format

Answer (score 1):

```
robocopy "c:\folder1\folder2" "d:\folder1\folder2" "img0001.jpg"
```

Since robocopy is not included in windows XP, this can be done with plain xcopy

```
xcopy "c:\folder1\folder2\img0001.jpg" "d:\folder1\folder2\"
```

Comment: robocopy doesn't support in windows XP. it shows err msg: as This command is not supported by the help utility.  Try "x /?".

Comment: @Ramakrishnan, sorry not to indicate it. My fault. If you are interested, it is a great tool. You can download if for xp from microsoft as it is included in the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657). Anyway, you are right, it is not a native windows XP tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%f in (img001.png img002.jpg img003.png) do copy /b "c:\folder1\folder2\%%f" "d:\folder1\folder2\"
```

Note that thw directory separator in windows is `\`, not `/`. `/` is used as a command-switch - `/b` in the above case means "copy in binary mode'.

Note that you do not say whether the batch should check whether the destination directory exists or whether the destination filename already exists.

```
md "d:\folder1\folder2" 2>nul
```

will force the destination filename to exist (`2>nul` suppresses the 'already exists ' message)

You can add an extra switch `/y` to the `copy` command to force overwrite in the case that the destination file already exists.

You can add `>nul` to the `copy` command to suppress the `1 file copied` message.

Comment: I didnt have any existing directory structure and all. What all i need is, just to copy the file from source to destination with the same kind of folder structure mentioned above. Note: The files can be either image or text files.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy that one file.  The target filename is not required but can be left in.

```
copy "c:\folder1\folder2\imgoo1.png" "D:\folder1\folder2\imgoo1.png"
```

This assumes that the folders already exist.